# excel index function with max

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some Excel sheets (qu1-qu7).

[image]

With this code I get the max value of row 17:

```
=MAX('qu1:qu7'!B17:Y17)
```

Now I need to get the date of this Max value : 28.02.2020

I tried this code:

```
=INDEX('qu1:qu7'!B3:X3;Match(MAX('qu1:qu7'!B17:Y17);'qu1:qu7'!B17:Y17))
```

But it does not work.

Comment: tried. Did not work.

Comment: They should both be in column `V` (22 minus 1 for starting from column `B`). Check the result of the `MATCH`-function. Does it throw an error, as the ranges of `INDEX` and `MATCH` are not the same?

Comment: I edited my code.

Comment: Try formula-evaluation on the formula tab to see, where the "does not work" occurs. To me, the formula looks fine, though you could add `,0` (`;0` in your case) to the `MATCH`-function to get exact matches.

Comment: The result is a #VALUE! error

Comment: I think the problem is with Match func. Because it return value error.

Comment: Please add the data to the post. Then i can try it myself. At least 2 cells of "Summe Kd."

Comment: See this article. [Article](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/locate-maximum-value.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unless INDEX MATCH is not compulsion you can try the following:

`=OFFSET($A$17,-13,MAX('qu1:qu7'!B17:Y17))`

This should work.

Comment: Unfortunately not